# Creating a Report System

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to create a report system in Laravel.

Here is my schema:

```
Schema::create('reports', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('reportable_id')->nullable();
    $table->string('reportable_type')->nullable();
    $table->string('body');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

What I want to try to achieve is when a user reports, the model that gets passed into the Route (i.e Thread, Reply, User, Post), gets recorded in the database.

```
Route::post('/report/{model}', 'ReportController@store');
```

I did some research and it's not possible to pass the Object into the request.

How do I go about creating this system? Are there any other alternatives I should consider?

Thanks!

Comment: Try with Middleware?

Comment: "I did some research and it's not possible to pass the Object into the request." - serialize it first.

Comment: Can you please explain Dai? Never serialized before... Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I'm at a loss. Any help would be appreciated :D

Comment: I'll try to solve it in the meantime, I think I can use the Relationships in the Report model to create depending on the model passed in?

Comment: better create a REST API for this, and post the data in request body

Comment: Hi @user1994 What would the route in the web.php look like if I create a REST API for this?

Comment: Route::post("report","YourController@function");

Comment: Also if you are going to make api then it will be in api.php file not in web.php file

Comment: Cant I make like an abstract class which accepts a model and then implement that somehow in the controller?

Comment: One way I was thinking is to just pass the Model as a string :D Is there any downsides to this besides it not being .... so elegant? I mean if Route Model binding isn't there .... I'll just bind it myself?

Comment: simply pass the model in request payload and make sure to serialize the data firstly.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how I would serialize the data? I've never done it before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227567/discussion-between-user1994-and-user123).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send model name and id in post request. Using input fields